# Query version info from jsf application

Tags: java, security, jsf, myfaces

I just stumbled upon a [paper](http://www.cigital.com/papers/download/dissecting_jsf_pt_aks_kr.pdf) on JSF security containing the following statement:

> In Suns RI JSF implementation, the
>   "com.sun.faces.disableVersionTracking"
>   conguration parameter is defined explicitly. By default, it is set to false which
>   means application running on the web server will throw the JSF version into
>   the response headers when the web client queries for it

But I don't understand how the web client is supposed to query for it? Is there a way to put extra (header) parameters to a request which makes JSF more chatty? I'm using MyFaces as the JSF implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That phrase is poorly written. Clients can't *specifically* query for JSF application version information. In fact, this is returned to *every* single HTTP request sent by the client. The JSF version information is set as `X-Powered-By` response header.

Basically, you should read "queries" as "sends a HTTP request".

Comment: Expected something like that, yet the phrase confused me. Thank you.